# Possible to use width=device-width and meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

In my header php in wordpress can I add both viewports:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
```

I want to be able to say `everything` displays using `viewport width 1024`, **unless** you are a mobile device below x pixels then use `width=device-width` instead.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-browser-detection/ and if it's a mobile browser, `echo` the good meta!

Answer (score 1):

With the good [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-browser-detection/) , it will be something like :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=<?php echo  (is_mobile()) ? "device-width" : "width=1024" ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jo, it sort of works but my styles are all over the place on the mobile version, they work when you use only device-width? The normal browser's okay at 1024. using child theme based on twenty twelve and so its running mobile first. I have media queries for the following: Starts with all mobile styling, then there is /* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
media screen and (min-width: 600px) this picks up iPad, online ipad generator shows all content but viewing on actual ipad only header/footer show, hence why switching this to width=1024, then last one media screen and (min-width: 960px)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what the issue is?    

You wan't to change the value of `viewport` attribute according to the width of the browser?

Comment: The content between the header and footer disappears when viewed on ipad but view in an ipad simulation on the screen it looks okay which means using firebug to find the issue is no good. Because the ipad version looks okay if using viewport content="width=1024" I thought I could just use that but that also affects the mobile phone version, I want a solution that will allow mobiles to use the initial css (its mobile first approach) using device-width but then force ipad and screen to use viewport width 1024. Does that make it any clearer? Sorry, probably not clearer but I did try.

Comment: Ok, you can make `is_ipad($version)` to test for ipad. ( the `$version` is optional, and allow to filter for a given version). Goto to the [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-browser-detection/) site to view all possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code

```
/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
/* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
/* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
/* some CSS here */
}

/* #### iPhone 4+ Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Tablets Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
/* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Desktops #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
/* some CSS here */
}
```